# in Photoshop CS4, how do I make an adjustment layer apply only to the layer directly beneath it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4

I know I can do this:

- select adjustment layer
- ctrl-click layer beneath it
- invert selection and delete

But this only captures the CURRENT shape of the lower layer. So if I later edit it, the mask won't be updated and I'll have to re-capture it. So what's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the adjustment tab, third icon in the footer row from the left, the one that looks like a slide switch.

[image: switch to select adjustment layer scope]